# What does "auto-wash" actually do?

Tags: technology, the-fifth-element

Recently, I needed a washer mechanic to come to my home to clean out the lines. He told us that we need to do an...

***auto-wash***

...from time-to-time to avoid problems, and that made me wonder about a famous LeeLoo scene in which Korben Dallas tries to hide her in the shower.

[LeeLoo auto-wash scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jv5QMgBJgbo)

She  came out shivering and learned a new word in English (part of her cultural acclimatization).

What does auto-wash actually do? If it is anything like what I had to do with my washer, it was a huge waste of water. And why was it so cold?

Comment: Mostly washes stuff, automatically.

Comment: Very funny...what? Dishes? Laundry? Scantily-clad  aliens?

Comment: Auto-shower for humans (and other species =) )

Comment: @Cascabel - I think you've hit the scantily-clad nail right on the head there.

Comment: @Cascabel: I suspect washing is pretty much washing. Here's my guess at their algorithm: `1. Lather. 2. Rinse. 3. Repeat.`

Comment: @PaulD.Waite When I was in the during the Vietnam era, the "Navy" shower was 30 second rinse, shut water off, lather, and then rinse again. Took less than 2 minutes. It's even in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navy_shower) Most guys worked their tooth-brushing into that also.

Comment: @Cascabel The incomparable efficiency of the manual military wash.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Actually...it is being adopted by many water conservationists...kind of like not flushing the toilet every time you pee or throw a tissue in the toilet.

Comment: Sometimes I flush the toilet just to remind it who’s really in charge.

Answer (score 2):

The 'auto-wash' function seems to simply be a wash cycle that activates automatically when someone gets into the shower.

In the [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1458174.The_Fifth_Element), the shower starts automatically but the warm water doesn't work well and Leeloo leaves the shower cold.

> “Leeloo,” he said, “hide in there, and don’t move!”
> Without hesitation, she jumped into the shower. The door closed behind her.
>
> ...
>
> Korben opened the shower. Leeloo was standing under the spray, shivering violently.
> “I’m sorry,” said Korben. “I forgot the hot water doesn’t work too well in this old racktower.” He dragged a blanket out of a corner and wrapped her in it.

Comment: So I am guessing that Korben does not make regular use of the faciities....

Comment: @Cascabel - Like most soldiers, he keeps clean the things that matter most, his feet and his guns.

Comment: He keeps his frickin' guns in a basket....don't look well-maintained to me:-)